# bson.json_util.loads is not consistent when converting $oid to ObjectID

Tags: python, json, mongodb, unicode, bson

**note**: I am using `from bson import json_util as json` in the code examples below.

I am trying to build a unit test that simulates reading a document from MongoDB.
Instead of reading the document from MongoDB, I insert (hard code) this data:

```
{"examsFltr": unicode(json.dumps({"taggingObjects": {"$oid": "54eaed40ab5db876b8450217"}))}
```

When I implement `json.loads` on this line, I get:

```
{"examsFltr": {unicode}u'{"taggingObjects": ObjectId("54eaed40ab5db876b8450217"))}
```

But when I implement `json.loads` on a MongoDB document I get:

```
{"examsFltr": {unicode}u'{"taggingObjects": {"$oid": "54eaed40ab5db876b8450217"}}'
```

My question is how can this happen that the same line returns different results, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You'll need to show more context. There's no situation in which calling `json.loads` on a document will give you an ObjectId value. Are you perhaps using [`bson.json_util.load`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html)?

Comment: Yess. I am using bson.json_util.load. Why are you asking? and I'll be happy to send more but can you be more specific on what could be relevant? @DanielRoseman

Comment: I can't understand why you think that is not relevant. You claimed that calling `json.loads` has unpredictably different results, but it turns out that is not the case, you are using two completely different functions. It should not surprise you that a different function has a different result.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think liad meant that she used json.loads for both and getting different results